# Adjustable height for BottomSheetBehaviour

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, share, bottom-sheet

I am using `BottomSheetBehaviour` for Share functionality.

I am trying to implement the following functionalities

- Lets say I have 20 apps on which I can share. So I need show 20 apps on bottom sheet as items(which will be a scrallable list view).
- Initially when the `Share` button is pressed, I want to fix the `BottomSheet` height to `screenHeight/2`
- When the user drag the `BottomSheet` upwards, I want to increase the height of `BottomSheet`, similar to `WrapContent`

`BottomSheet` is pretty confusing as I am new to it. Can anyone guide me or give any references.

Code:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
     app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Share via..."/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
View bottom_sheet;
BottomSheetBehavior bSheet
ListView listview;`
bottom_sheet=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
bSheet= BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);
listView= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

share code:

```
public void shareKnapp() {
        bSheet.setHideable(true);
        if(bSheet.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED){
            bSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }else{
        bSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//Share funtionality
           });
    }
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix I posted the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `BottomSheetBehaviour` to be exactly half of the screen you can do so by first getting your display dimensions and then setting them as followed:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metrics);
int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

bSheet.setPeekHeight(screenHeight);
```

You can now set the default state to `STATE_HIDDEN`and reveal it on the click of your share button with `bSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);`.

Now, if you have a `ListView` in your bottom sheet, it should automatically scroll when the users drags it.

Additionally I would consider taking a look at the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, as it pretty much provides what you need. `BottomSheetBehaviour` is more likely useful if you have a persistent part of your screen that needs to be scrolled from the bottom (And it not hidden all the time).